# Google Sheets Scripts - For each cell in range, get row number where cell has specific value, copy row to first blank row in range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I come from a VB background and am having some trouble implementing a scripts solution for Sheets, I imagine the function is fairly basic but am not yet sure how to express it in JS. The goal is to loop through each cell in a range (Sheet 1, Q3:Q1000), get the row number where the cell in that range has the value "TRUE", copy/cut the entirety of each row on Sheet 1 that meets that qualification (or simply store the values and skip the copy/paste step), paste the values to the first unused row on a separate sheet (Sheet2), then delete the original row on Sheet1.

So far, I have managed to put together this crude function which successfully finds the row number of the first cell in the given range containing the specified value, but it returns NaN if there is more than one occurrence of the value in the range. Any indication as to what I am doing wrong will be helpful, thank you.

```
function onEditTesting(e) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
const range = "Q3:1000";
var whereTrue = "TRUE";
var range = sheet.getRange("Q3:Q1000");
var rangeValues = sheet.getRange(range).getValues();

var i = []; 
for (var y = 0; y < rangeValues.length; y++) {
   if(rangeValues[y] == whereTrue){
      i.push(y);
   }
}

var Row = Number(i)+Number(range.getRow());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach using [onEdit() Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

### Sample Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var cell = e.range;
  var sourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var lastCol = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  Logger.log("row: "+row+" maxCol: "+lastCol+" col: "+col+" val: "+cell.getDisplayValue()+" sheet: "+sourceSheet.getName());
  //Check if modified cell is in column Q (index 17) in Sheet1 has a value of TRUE
  if(sourceSheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 17 && cell.getDisplayValue() == "TRUE"){
    //Append current row to the destination sheet
    var values = sourceSheet.getRange(row,1,1,lastCol).getValues();
    Logger.log(values);
    destinationSheet.appendRow(values.flat());
    
    //Delete current row
    sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

### What it does?

1. Get the sourceSheet and cell modified using e.range event object
2. Check the cell modified if it is in column Q (index 17) of Sheet1 having a value of "TRUE". I used [Range.getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue) to get the actual string value of the cell because when I test it using [Range.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) it gave me a boolean object
3. Get the row values from the first column up to the last column of the current row using [Sheet.getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) and [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
4. Append the current row values of the source sheet to your destination sheet using [Sheet.appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) where `rowContents` is a 1-d array and since the [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) returns a 2-d array, I used [array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert 2-d array to 1-d array
5. Delete the current row using [Sheet.deleteRow(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition)

### Output:

Before (Sheet1):

[image]

After (Sheet1):

[image]

After (Sheet2):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution. I know it is outside the scope of the original question, but is it possible to trigger this script alone rather than on an edit event? The reason I ask is that it appears to run endlessly without moving the data when executed as an edit event.

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can use @cooper's solution and create a [Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers). Basically, when you add trigger, select Time-driven as event source and specify other options required

Comment: Oh, what do you mean by alone? sorry, do you want a button click or a custom menu that can call the function to move the rows? (but for both events, you need to use @cooper's solution)

Answer (score 2):

```
function moveData() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const vs=ssh.getRange(3,1,ssh.getLastRow()-2,ssh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let oA=[];
  let d=0;
  vs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[16]=='TRUE') {
      oA.push(r);
      ssh.deleteRow(i+3-d++);
    }
  });
  dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oa);
}
```